# Civicrm Menu not showing in Drupal 9

Tags: menubar, drupal-9, civicrm

searched for this on the web but did not really sth helpful. Any chance someone here can make a hint.
Drupal 9.4.5
Civicrm 5.64

Fresh installation, used composer 2.5.8
no errors during install
no errors when activating civicrm-core in drupal extensions

various searches, cleaning paths, flushing caches etc

In the meanwhile I found out that when loading CiviCRM it looks in libraries/civicrm/core/b.... for various files
But these are located in the vendor folder

strange enough : the civicrm_settings.php says civicrm_root is in the vendor folder, but the admin page of Civicrm (ressource url's) says they should be in the library path.

any idea out there?

Comment: Not clear what paths you aer asking about. presumably /civicrm/*. Have you tried adjusting themes - both the drupal ones and the civicrm offerings?

Comment: also note, many more civi eyeballs at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: yes tried around changing themes etc

Answer (score 0):

After installation civicrm:publish through composer is required.
This publishes all the civicrm assets to the library folder
This swiped away all the http404 errors and the civicrm menu loaded correctly.